# How to prevent Android CursorLoader to reload?

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-cursorloader

I'm writing an android vocabulary learning app.

On `MainActivity`, I'm using a `CursorLoader` to load a vocabulary **list** from **database**.

When the user clicks **next** `button`, current vocabulary status will be updated.

But every time the vocabulary status updated, `onLoadFinished` is called and a new cursor is passed in.

I know it's because I'm using `ContentProvider` and set notification `URI`, but when I update vocabulary status, I'm using `URI` with specific `id`:

```
ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
cv.put(VocabularyContract.VocabularyEntry.COLUMN_STATUS, status);    
getContentResolver().update(ContentUris.withAppendedId(VocabularyContract.VocabularyEntry.CONTENT_URI, vocabId),
            cv,
            null,
            null);
```

But the `uri` used in `onCreateLoader` is different, without `id`:

```
CursorLoader learnCursorLoader = new CursorLoader(this,
                        VocabularyContract.VocabularyEntry.CONTENT_URI,
                        null,
                        VocabularyContract.VocabularyEntry.COLUMN_STATUS + "=" + VocabularyContract.VocabularyEntry.STATUS_LEARNING,
                        null,
                        null);
```

Why is it still reloaded?
How to prevent it to reload?

Comment: If this is your own database, why are you using a `ContentProvider`?

Comment: Actually it's a project assignment and using ContentProvider is one of the requirements.

Comment: IMHO, that approach has been out of date for years. Regardless, my guess is that `CursorLoader` sets up a `ContentObserver` for everything at `VocabularyContract.VocabularyEntry.CONTENT_URI` and its descendants, which would include your specific `Uri`.